# If someone says Android message API what it related to? What classes it consists in?

Tags: android

Recently started Android programming. Developed 3 apps using threads, UI API, telephony API.
My quesion is if someone says Android message API what it related to? What classes it consists in?

"Actually I have seen this in an Android job post"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are referring to android.os.Message, android.os.Handler, android.os.MessageQueue, android.os.Messenger; all of which are documented in the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html). There may be a few utility classes I've not mentioned, but those are the ones I make use of.

If you have seen this mentioned in a job specification, they are expecting you to have knowledge of the messaging API and how to make effective use of it, which is a fair requirement since you would be writing code that runs on a mobile platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes my assumption was the same as those classes you mentioned. But on some corner I was thinking it's not. Now it is confirmed. one good thing is I used android.os.Handler before using core Threads :-)